# How is Encryption Actually Used in Public Networks at This Moment?

Tags: encryption, traffic-analysis

Has anyone done a study, assembled a snapshot, of **how encryption is actually being used** on the Internet at this moment?

So many companies do traffic analysis, the usage share of operating systems, etc., and one imagines that national-level agencies do this too, perhaps in incredible detail, but does any open-source information exist that quantifies the use of cryptographic hashes, asymmetric and symmetric algorithms, cryptographic libraries, etc.--and the services they provide?

Reliable data is certainly available.

Such a study on current use could answer many interesting questions:

> How much global message and email traffic is being encrypted all the
>   way through an ISP?  With what?  How much is GnuPG being used? What cryptographic primitives are actually in decline? What services-- confidentiality, integrity, non-repudiation,
>   availability, non-availability (!), authentication-- are really being
>   requested, and what is their usage share?

**Does a detailed, open-source (or compromised) study of global encryption use exist?**

Comment: That would be a **mammoth task**,  I don't think such data exists but let's see what others have to say. Also,  "Encryption used across the world" is probably way too broad and unrealistic. "Used on public networks / Internet", maybe?

Comment: You can make a research on how is the traffic distributed first, for example 10% google, 15% faceboock, and then make SSL connections to those services and analyze the TLS parameters, ciphers and extrapolate them, this just from network perspective.

Comment: There have been published surveys of TLS servers and clients analyzing which ciphersuites (i.e. which primitives) they support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to email, Google reports regularly on the use of TLS on incoming/outgoing mails through its servers, which is significant sample size given the popularity of GMail. See below.

https://transparencyreport.google.com/safer-email/overview

You can examine the data in quite some detail to see TLS usage by domain, country etc.

They also see to have other reports on HTTPS usage etc. although I haven’t checked them out myself.